# Remove Ubuntu from dual boot without installation disk/USB

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, uninstall

I have a messed up Ubuntu 22.04 installation. When I boot it, it says "Windows failed to start" and everything that says to remove it requires a, installation disk/USB.

Many have also said that I should go into UEFI, but on a Surface, since I installed it on my disk, I think its on Windows boot manager, and it doesn't specify "Windows 10" and "Ubuntu".

Is there possibly any way I can remove the dual boot from a Surface without an installation disk?

Comment: I really don't understand your question, but I think you are confusing stuff and trying to fix stuff that has nothing to do with your problem. When it displays "Windows failed to start", it's problem in Windows or Windows boot manager (that you are using what I understand), and it has nothing to do with GRUP2 or Ubuntu.

Comment: So how do I delete it and just let it automatically boot to windows 10

Comment: You may need to follow through this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/143482/231142.  Without media you should be able to boot into Windows Recovery mode and follow through to repair the boot first then remove Ubuntu from Windows.

Comment: From what repair exactly? If your talking about startup repair it said it cant repair